# Нужна помощь по progress bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Делаю портфолио, нужен progress bar. 
При скроле вниз на одном из блоков который вызжает при помощи wow.js должна быть шкала. Хочу сделать её через progress bar, но инфы годной не нашёл.
Помогите годными статейками про progress bar или как можно по-вашему это всё реализовать ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669269/jquery-skill-bar-effect-starts-when-you-scroll-to-the-section

Comment: Скилл не тянет на 52%)))

Comment: Посмотрите как устроен [Progress от Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/)

Answer (score 1):

Такой функционал проще всего сделать без wow.js. Можно определить видимость блока при скроллинге (window.onscroll), и в момент видимости (можно использовать getBoundingClientRect()) использовать анимацию (animation css)